# Linear algebra with 2-dim. functions instead of matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, integration, real-numbers, topological-vector-spaces

I just thought about what would happen if we try to do matrix calculus with functions $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ instead of matrices.

The matrix multiplication would be something like

$$
(f \times g)(x, y) = \int_\mathbb R f(x, z) g(z, y) dz.
$$

Is this theory developed somewhere? Does it have a name? Are there interesting results? What is the space of "invertible functions"? Are there determinants?

Now a matrix corresponds to a linear map between vector spaces of finite dimension. Similarly, a linear map could be defined via an integral kernel by
$$
h \mapsto \int_{\mathbb R} f(x, z) h(z) dz.
$$

If we want the integrals to converge, we should perhaps require the functions to be contained within an appropriate space. Furthermore, we then should want the product of two functions as given above to be within that space again. As far as I can tell, bump functions would certainly do, but I'm sure one can do better.

Comment: It has names. The first operation is called convolution. The second is a linear transformation on some function space. The area of mathematics which deals with these questions is called Functional Analysis and is an extension of linear algebra to function spaces. It has applications in PDE. However, the question as it is written is too broad and unclear.

Comment: Hello, I am familiar with functional analysis, and the definition of the convolution I know from this subject looks different (we deal with functions of one variable each).

Comment: Could you further elaborate on what is unclear about the question I asked before killing it?

Comment: I do not agree at all to close this question: I think that on the contrary it is very interesting

Comment: I think you can probably get rid of the integrals convergence issues by considering $C_1[0,1]$ or any compact interval for that matter, the interest being that you have a sort of a non-countable dimension vector space. Now the problem with your matrix generalization is that it only accounts for continuous endomorphisms so it doesn't cover the whole set of linear maps.

Comment: "if we insert ... instead of matrices into linear algebra": this is completely unclear. One does not insert matrices into linear algebra; rather they come up naturally as a means to represent linear maps between finite dimensional vector spaces relative to a pair of bases. Functions $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ don't do that, so they cannot replace matrices in any way.

Comment: Done, although I have the feeling that I lost clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The operation

$$h \mapsto \int_{a}^b f(x, z) h(z) dz$$

is called an **operator** with **kernel** $f$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform (no relationship with the other meaning of the word in linear algebra). You have noticed that, instead of taking $\mathbb{R}$ in its whole, I have taken bounds $a,b$.

One of the important kernels is $e^{-2i \pi xz}$, associated with $a=-\infty, b=\infty$ : it defines the **Fourier transform** ; in the same way for many other transforms, Laplace (with $a=0,b=\infty$) Mellin,** ....that are listed in the Wikipedia article.

In most cases, this two dimensional kernel has the form $K(x,z)=k(x-z)$ for a certain function $k:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and in this way, and in this way only, **one finds back the convolution** $k*f$ !

(this is for example the case for the very important kernel $K(x,z)=sinc(x-z)$ in signal processing).

See, for the Hibert space aspect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space

Like for matrices, these transforms may have eigenvectors, eigenvalues that may constitute a basis (in a the sense of basis in a Hilbert space); using such bases, one can decompose, under certain conditions, these transformations under what is known as the Karhunen-Loève decomposition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem which is a cousin of the SVD decomposition, etc.

Comment: Yes, my *second* operator does look like a convolution if the kernel has the form given by you.

Comment: Yes, I have been speaking all the way long about your second formula. I have not addressed the generalization of determinants (in fact, I don't know any, and I think there is no natural generalization) whereas one can obtain a generalization of the trace.

Comment: Maybe this is possible using a space of bijective functions together with a product integral. Would be fairly surprising though if no one ever did this generalisation.